# Replacing HVAC System in Dallas

Tags: hvac, replacement

I am a new home owner and still learning a lot. I have a 23 year old YORK HVAC system that I need to replace. I’ve received multiple quotes, apart from replacing the unit and also the furnace what else should a quote for a replacement system include. I get different parts on different estimates. Hard to tell what’s legitimate.

Comment: Details on warranty, possibly annual maintenance cost

Comment: Ask also for the hourly rate: Often you add some last minute requests, that aren't included in the quote..

Comment: Is there an actual question here?

Answer (score 1):

Consider not going furnace, get a modern heat pump that works down to deep cold.

System should be all new air handler, evaporator, condenser unit, and piping between the two, plus connection to your existing ductwork.  New or it fits in your existing drip tray if it's upstairs.

Answer (score 1):

Ask for a reference from the trades, that you could phone up for a chat. Or ask neighbours who they may have used.  Or go to the website of the manufacturer, They will have registered dealers/installers, use them.

Answer (score 0):

Call your town's building department and ask if replacement of the HVAC system requires a building permit and inspection. If it does, make sure the quote / contract states that the contractor will obtain the permit and that the job will pass inspection as quoted.

Otherwise, the contractor may well leave out electrical upgrades that have become newly required over the past 23 years (such as a shutoff within sight of the outside equipment and a 120V outlet within 25 feet) and stick you with an additional bill "because upgrades were not included", even though *he knew* they would be required.